# it it possible to make a function return true, false or a list of objects?

Tags: java, information-retrieval, data-handling

### Introduction to the program

I'm working on a program which stores data like the following:

**- Facts:** A combination of  a list of properties (or just one) and a true/false value(called the "truth" value). For example:

> parent('John' , 'John jr') , true

where the property of `John` being a parent of `John jr` is true. The code I use for storing a fact:

```
public class Fact implements Serializable{
    private boolean truth;
    private ArrayList<Property> properties;

    public Fact(){
        truth = false;
        properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
    }

    //more constructors, getters, setters and other functions  which are not important for this question...
```

**- Rules:** Used to obtain information from facts. They work by having a fact (which I call the derivative fact) imply another fact (which I call the impliant fact):

> parent('x' , 'y') => child('y', 'x')

This means that by applying the rule to the fact above we can determine that `John jr` is a child of `John`.

### **Properties of rules:**

**negativity:**

Rules can be either "positive" (if the derivative is true, the impliant is true):

> parent('x' , 'y') => child('y', 'x')

or "negative"  (if the derivative is true, the impliant is false):

> parent('x' , 'y') => not child('y', 'x')

**reversitivity:**

they can also be "reversive" (if the derivative is false, the impliant is true/false):

> not parent('x' , 'y') => child('y', 'x')

or (if also negative):

> not parent('x' , 'y') => not child('y', 'x')

or "non-reversive" (if the derivative is false, the impliant is unknown):

> not parent('x' , 'y') => (unknown)

The code I use to store rules looks like this:

```
public class Rule implements Serializable{
    private Property derivative;
    private Property impliant;
    private boolean negative;
    private boolean reversive;

    public Rule(Property derivative, Property impliant) throws InvalidPropertyException{
        if(!this.validRuleProperty(derivative) || !this.validRuleProperty(impliant))
            throw new InvalidPropertyException("One or more properties are invalid");
        this.derivative = derivative;
        this.impliant = impliant;
        negative = false;
        reversive = false;
    }

    //again more constructors, getters, setters and other functions  which are not important for this question...
```

### **InformationSets**

facts and rules are stored in `InformationSets` which bundle these facts and rules together so the user can "question" the information inside. This can be done in 2 different ways:

**1.Fact Check:** Check if a fact is true. This will, given a fact, will return either true or false based on the truth value of that fact. for example the user can ask:

> parent('John' , 'John jr')?

and the program will return `true` while:

> parent('John jr' , 'John jr')?

will return `false`.

The question mark indicates the user want to ask a 'fact check' question.

**1.Impliant Check:** This will, for a given fact(called the question-fact), return a list of facts for each rule which can be applied to the question-fact. For example:

> parent('John' , 'John jr')=>

this will return:

> child('John jr', 'John')

The arrow indicates the user want to ask a 'Impliant check' question.

Questions are coded like this:

```
public class Question {
    Fact questionFact;
    String operator;

    public Question(Fact questionFact, String operator) throws InvalidOperatorException{
        if(!validOperator(operator))
            throw new InvalidOperatorException("The operator is invalid");
        this.questionFact = questionFact;
        this.operator = operator;
    }
```

Inside the `Operator` field I store `?` or `=>` according to which kind of question the user want to ask.

### **The Problem**

I'm currently at the point where I need to write the method that will ask questions to a given informationSet. So I would need a method that given a question and an informationset returns either `true`, `false` or a list of facts. As far as I know this is not possible in java.

I tried to make a separate method for each question which kinda works but this also causes a problem as I would like to be able to write something like:

`informationSet.ask(question);`

and have the `ask()` method deal with both types of question so I don't have to check which kind of question the user is asking on inside the user-interface code but rather have the back end of the program work it out.

What could be a good way to do this?

Comment: But you can encapsulate your three options in a class Response with two fields: an enum ResponseType (TRUE, FALSE, FACTS) and a list of facts. As you have stated, the same method can not return two different types in Java, boolean and Fact.

Comment: That could be an option. I just need to make sure not to use both at the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the most obvious solution would be to implement your custom response class.

---

Another idea would be to consider using [Either](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Either.html) from [Vavr](http://vavr.io) which is a solution designed to hold either (pun intended!) values of type A or B exclusively.

So, it could look like:

```
Either<Boolean, List<Fact>> result = foo();
```

Then, you can leverage FP Optional/Stream API-like for manipulating the result:

If you want to access the left side:

```
result.left()
  .map(...)
  .filter(...)
  // ...
```

If you want to access the right side:

```
result.right()
  .map(...)
  .filter(...)
  // ...
```

Comment: I've gone with the fist option. A response class which also stores the type of question which has been asked by the user. This way I can easily check wiht the user asked for and extract the data from the response accordingly. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the proposition of *Grzegorz*, You should keep in mind Java is strongly typed. This doesn't mean you can't return an **Either** object; which by definition can hold different Classes (types).

But in Java logic, I think it is better to implement more specifies methods, at a narrower granularity (this has many benefits in Object Oriented design, like sharing code and scalability).

So I suggest to propose two methods, one for Boolean, and another for array result. You then make a condition test in a caller function.

Comment: yes that would work however that would mean that I have to do that inside the code of the GUI and I'd like to keep the back end and GUI of the program as separated as possible.

Comment: Why is it that you can't do the test in the back-end ? ask yourself, you may find an alternative. Anyway, `Either` is there.